# Troubles with arrays

Tags: arrays, jgrasp

Hello all I'm currently working on a program that prints out sales data, the only part I have left is printing out the summary of the sales data Heres a bit of my code that I'm having trouble with.

```
public static void DisplayRegionSummary( int sales[][] ) 
    {
         int locationsum=0;

         System.out.printf("Location    Sales\n");    
         for (int l=1; l<=4; l++) 
         {
           String[] names = { "North", "East", "South", "West"};
           for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
           {
              System.out.print(names[i]);




           locationsum = 0;

           for(int d=1; d<=4; d++ ) 
           locationsum+=sales[l][d];
           }


           System.out.printf("%6d\n", locationsum);

           }
```

So what i'm trying to do here is print out one element on my String array on each one of the lines but it ends up printing something like this

```
    Location             Sales
    NorthEastSouthWest     0
    NorthEastSouthWest     0
```

I debugged it and i see thats its printing the entire array names all on one line each time it goes through the for loop and I'm not really sure how to fix it, I tried to put it in the

```
System.out.printf("%6d\n", locationsum);
```

piece of code but it just kept giving me error's,but I'm honestly not sure on how to code it in there, any tips would be loved!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So i've gotten all of the String elements to print on each line with this

```
 int locationsum=0;

         System.out.printf("Location    Sales\n");    
         for (int l=1; l<=4; l++) 
         {

           locationsum = 0;

           for(int d=1; d<=4; d++ ) 

           locationsum+=sales[l][d];
           }
          String[] names = { "North", "East", "South", "West"};

           for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
           {
              System.out.print(names[i]);

           System.out.printf("%6d\n", locationsum);

           } 


    }
```

But then it does this and doesn't take any of my sales values I put in

```
Location    Sales
North     0
East     0
South     0
West     0
```